# disallow passing of rvalue reference to a function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

We have the following convenience function that fetches a value from a map
or returns a fallback default value if key not found.

```
template <class Collection> const typename Collection::value_type::second_type&
    FindWithDefault(const Collection& collection,
                    const typename Collection::value_type::first_type& key,
                    const typename Collection::value_type::second_type& value) {
      typename Collection::const_iterator it = collection.find(key);
      if (it == collection.end()) {
        return value;
      }
      return it->second;
    }
```

The problem with this function is that it allows passing a temporary object as third argument which would be a bug. For example:

```
const string& foo = FindWithDefault(my_map, "");
```

Is it possible to disallow passing rvalue references to the third argument in some way by using 
std::is_rvalue_reference and static assert?

Comment: It feels really intuitive to pass `""` there. It would be better to find a way to prevent `FindWithDefault` from being bound to a reference, except I don't think there is one. Anyway, it would be better to simply make `foo` a value in this example.

Comment: The other problem with this question is that you've jumped to what you think is the solution, rather than stating the problem. In doing so, you've focused on rvalue references but that is not the only problem; an lvalue reference-to-`const`-temporary will bite you just as hard. Perhaps take the default `value` by value.

Comment: You could return by value instead of returning by reference. This seems quite natural for a find-with-default.

Comment: If you disallow passing a rvalue, the user will create a variable and pass it. He will not be warned that the returned value is a reference on its variable. This seems dangerous and flawed, except if you write a big red warning about this in the class documentation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding this additional overload should work (untested):

```
template <class Collection>
const typename Collection::value_type::second_type&
FindWithDefault(const Collection& collection,
                const typename Collection::value_type::first_type& key,
                const typename Collection::value_type::second_type&& value) = delete;
```

Overload resolution will select this overload for rvalue references and the `= delete` makes it a compile time error. Alternatively, if you want to specify a custom message, you could go for

```
template <class Collection>
const typename Collection::value_type::second_type&
FindWithDefault(const Collection& collection,
                const typename Collection::value_type::first_type& key,
                const typename Collection::value_type::second_type&& value) {
    static_assert(
        !std::is_same<Collection, Collection>::value, // always false
        "No rvalue references allowed!");
}
```

The `std::is_same` is there to make the `static_assert` dependent on the template parameter, otherwise it would cause a compilation error even when the overload is not called.

EDIT: Here is a minimal complete example:

```
void foo(char const&) { };
void foo(char const&&) = delete;

int main()
{
    char c = 'c';
    foo(c);   // OK
    foo('x'); // Compiler error
}
```

MSVC gives the following error here for the second call to `foo`:

```
rval.cpp(8) : error C2280: 'void foo(const char &&)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
        rval.cpp(2): See declaration of 'foo'
```

The first call, however, works fine and if you comment out the second then the program compiles.

Comment: temporary object != rvalue reference. You can have a const& to a temporary object.

Comment: @user1095108: True, but then the the temporary will stay alive at least as long as the reference, and it is not so easy to pass this accidentally (I assume you mean `char const& ct = 't'; foo(ct);`).

Comment: Thanks! I did not know you could use 'delete' modifier for global functions.

Comment: Much cleaner than my first thought, which was take a universal reference and SFINAE filter that it should be an lvalue of type `Collection::value_type::second_type`.