# How to force the compiler not to accept rvalues when passing const reference in constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, pass-by-reference

I have the following code in VS2019 (haven't tested with other compilers yet).

```
class A
{
    // A should be a pure virtual class
};

class B
{
    const A* member;
public:
    B(const A& arg) : member{ &arg } {}
    // Solves the problem
    // B(const A&& arg) = delete;
    void setA(const A& arg) { member = &arg; }
    // Solves the problem
    // setA(const A&& arg) = delete;
    void setA(const A& arg) { member = &arg; }
};

int main()
{
    B b(A{});
    b.setA( A{} ); 
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the behavior in set function is what's expected - it doesn't accept an rvalue. On the other way, constructor happily accepts the an rvalue without warning or compiler errors. As I see it, the compiler assumes copy semantics in case of constructor, but correctly resolves it in the second case.
This behavior does not occur if I pass A& instead of const A&

Is there a way to force the compiler not accept rvalues in the constructor?
A one way to solve that was to delete the B(const A&&) constructor. Is there a more elegant way / uniform way to do it? Making constructor explicit still does not solve the problem.

Edit - the suggested link doesn't answer my question. As the solution suggested there (namely explicitly deleting const rvalue reference) was already mentioned in my question. I was asking whether there exists another way except explicitly deleting the overload. I am also trying to understand whether it is a bug (in the compiler or the standard) or it's the way it should be.

Comment: pardon me but `setA` _does accept_  an rvalue. You miswrote the statement.  `b.setA( A{} );`

Comment: You're right. Just noticed it. Fixing it. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disallow passing of rvalue reference to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739974/disallow-passing-of-rvalue-reference-to-a-function)

Comment: Not exactly. Explicitly deleting the overloaded function was suggested in the question. I was asking whether there is another "uniform" way. I might be wrong, explicitly deleting const rvalue reference function is kind of tedious. I don't see an answer in the linked question as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of constructor, deleting is not only most elegant, but a recommended method  ( rule of five - rule of zero).

`b.setA( A{} );` would accept both rvalue reference and general reference.

```
B b(A{});
A a;
b.setA( a );
```

To avoid this you have to use delete overloaded version:

```
void setA(const A&& arg) = delete;
```

Comment: I updated the question and fixed the error with {} instead of (). The second part of the answer should be corrected

Comment: I might be wrong, but rule of five is about B(const B&) and B(B&&) - namely about copy and move semantics of B. They are not B(const A&) and B(A &&). This is not the case, I think. The problem here is that the function that accepts (const A&) assumes that we have copy semantics, which is not the case here. As I've mentioned, writing same functions with having A& in signature instead of const A& do not have this problem.

Comment: @RazielMagius rule of five is extension one of three  saying that class need move semantics,  the five special functions defined if they to be used. Rule of zero says that we can avoid writing default version if we don't need them, by utilizing value semantics of existing types. Integral outcome out of two rules combined, is inversion of rule of five, is that if we do NOT need move semantics, we have to delete respective member functions.